# Unset multiple intems in array

Tags: php

Is there a PHP built-in function to unset multiple array items by key?

That would be a native equivalent of:

```
foreach($badElements as $k) {
    unset($allElements[$k]);
}
```

or, even better:

```
$keys = array_keys($badElements);
foreach($keys as $k) {
    unset($allElements[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an array of the keys you want to remove and loop through, explicitly unsetting them.
Examples:

```
$removeKeys = array('name', 'email');

foreach($removeKeys as $key) {
   unset($badElements[$key]);
}
```

Or you could point the variable to a new array that has the keys removed.

```
$badElements = array_diff_key($badElements, array_flip($removeKeys));
```

or pass all of the array members to unset().

```
unset($badElements['name'],  $badElements['email'])
```

Answer (score 3):

The following doesn't fullfill your requirement in complete since it's **not in-situ**. But maybe you're ok with copying the array:

```
$v = array("lol"=>"blub", "lal"=>"blab", "lulz"=>"gagh");
$k = array("lol", "lulz");

var_dump(array_diff_key($v, array_flip($k)));
```

[ [run it on codepad](http://codepad.org/ghtrRK52) ]